# How to change between fullscreen and overlayed chat with button click event in converse.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, converse.js

I'm trying to put a button to change overlayed view to fullscreen, and another one from overlayed to fullscreen without using HTML redirection.

Tried to use `converse.api.settings.update` but it does not work, looks like it's not rendering the page with `view_mode` variable updated.

Tried with the next code in a function, and even added `this.render()`, but not working:

```
converse.initialize({
  view_mode: 'fullscreen'
});

_converse.api.settings.update({
  view_mode: 'fullscreen'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, but I wanted to "on the fly".

Finally I achieved it "on the fly" but making some tricks and probably wrong stuff, but what I did was to remove all classes in DOM referring to 'converse-overlayed' and later, initialize again the plugin:

```
converse.initialize({ 
... view_mode: 'fullscreen' 
});
```

Same for the opposite.

Comment: Converse isn't designed in a way so that you can call `converse.initialize` multiple times per session. This is undefined behavior and I'd be quite surprised if everything simply continues working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relevant API documentation.

[_converse.api.settings.update](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/-_converse.api.settings.html#.update) isn't used to change a configuration setting. It "*allows new configuration settings to be specified, or new default values for existing configuration settings to be specified.*"

So what you're doing there is simply setting a new default value, which is not the same as changing the value during runtime.

All configuration settings get set on the `_converse` object, so to change one you can simply assign a new value, for example `_converse.view_mode = 'fullscreen';`.

This won't have any immediate effect however because Converse doesn't yet support changing the `view_mode` on the fly.